# cookieless session issue with the url

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies, session-state, web.config-transform

when setting   `<sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>` in my `web.config`, I am getting strange url, how can I get rid of this.

here is the my url:

```
myhost:1578/%28S%28vzozelw3hgtqi22ndvyndzn1%29%29/default.aspx
```

but it should be `myhost:1578/default.aspx`

I not prefer using cookeless,but as I mentioned this question before

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626417/uplodify-session-issue-with-ff

.Only whne I use cookieless ,my second problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("default.aspx")
```

[Cookieless Session State Asp.net](http://dotnetfarrukhabbas.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/cookieless-session-state-asp-net/) 
[Cookieless ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Comment: is there easyier way to do that?

Comment: i think only this two ways `<sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>` and like my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
string urlConverted = Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("default.aspx");
buttonId.NavigateUrl = urlConverted;
```

[refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.applyapppathmodifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)